# When a player is revived, do they get their buffed health back?

Tags: brink

When an injured player takes cover to heal, their health only refills up to the next pip marker - usually if you're covering for health this means your health was very low, and so you heal to no buffs (until a Medic comes along and re-buffs your health for you).

But, when a Medic revives an incapacitated player, do they return with unbuffed health, or with any additional pips intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested it out on 360. You will return with unbuffed health. Does not matter if another medic revives you, or you self-revive.

Would actually make for a nice ability for a medic, come to think of it. Being able to revive/buff in one go would save a pip, but be pretty situational.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case, but kept being too busy playing to remember to check until it was time to sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Officially no, you do not get your health buff back, but if the medic who healed you is nice enough he will give you a buff himself once you are standing up again.